# G is group of order pq, pq are primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

**Problem.**

Let $G$ be a group of order $pq$ such that $p$ and $ q$ are prime integers.

I am to show that every proper subgroup of $G$ is cyclic.

**My attempt.**

What I know: Any element $a$ divides $pq$ and $a^{pq} = e$.

The order of subgroups $H$ divide $pq$ by Lagrange.

If I could show that $G$ is cyclic, then all subgroups must be cyclic.

If I can show that $G$ is a group of prime order, then I can show that it is cyclic.

I'm not sure what more I can do here...I've tried looking at Fermat's Little Theorem but I can't seem to properly understand it and how it could affect my problem..

Comment: What orders can a proper subgroup of $G$ have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Every proper nontrivial subgroup have prime orders.

---

If $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots p_t^{a_t}$ ,where $p_i$'s are different primes,then the only divisors of $n$ are of the form $p_1^{b_1}p_2^{b_2}\dots p_t^{b_t}$ where $0\leq b_i \leq a_i$ for all $i=1,2,\dots,t$.

Comment: Thank you, but why is this true?

Comment: @user3200098, by Lagrange Theorem the order of every subgroup of a finite group divides the order of group.

Comment: Yes but $pq$ is not necessarily prime just because $p$ and $q$ are respectively. Our subgroups divide $pq$, by Lagrange.

Comment: @user3200098 Nobody said $pq$ is prime: in fact we *know* it is *not* because primes $p,q$ divide it. Just think: the size of *proper* subgroups divides $pq$, and they cannot have order $pq$... what does that leave?

Comment: @user3200098, Since $p$ and $q$ are primes so the only divisors of $|G|=pq$ are $1, p, q$ and $pq$.

Comment: I didn't realize that the product of two primes is only divided by the primes, 1 and itself...Guess you learn something new every day. Thank you.

Comment: Thinking further about this...Since 1 divides $ \mid G \mid $ then since the subgroups of order 1 have a single elements, are they always automatically cyclic? It's very intuitive that they are, but I just want to be very sure because I've burned myself on assuming in this course.

Comment: @user3200098, The only subgroup of order $1$ is $\{e\}$ where $e$ is the identity element and it's clear that $e$ generates this subgroup because for every integer $n$ we have $e^n=e$, so yes $\{e\}=\left\langle {e} \right\rangle$ is cyclic.