# Subgroups of a group of order $pq$, $p,q$ are primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

There seem to be many problems about the subgroups of a group $G$ of order $pq$, $p,q$ are primes, like [G is group of order pq, pq are primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697823/g-is-group-of-order-pq-pq-are-primes), [Generators of a Group of order $pq$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210385/generators-of-a-group-of-order-pq).
Mine is a little bit different.

Claim 1: $G$ has 4 subgroups

From Sylow's theorem, there are at least 4 subgroups, but what we know to the best is that there are at least one for order $p$ and at least one for order $q$, but we cannot specify the exact number.

Claim 2: $G$ is communicative

I do think so because if $G = S_3$ which is the permutation group of $3$ elements. Then $|G| = 3!=6=2\times 3$, but this is not an Abelian group.

How should we prove there are exact one subgroup of order $p$ and order $q$?

Comment: Have a look at Sylow's Second Theorem, if I recall correctly it says that if the number of Sylow-p subgroups is $n_p$, then $n_p \equiv 1\pmod{p}$

Comment: @Nasenhaar thanks! Let me check it

Comment: Even simpler, Sylow's theorem also says that $n_p$ divides $m$, whenever $|G|=p^\alpha m$.

Comment: @Couchy311 yeah so we must have the number is exactly 1

Answer (score 1):

There are only $2$ different groups of order $pq$. We may assume that $p<q$. If $q$ does not divide $p-1$, then the group is isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_{pq}$. Otherwise the group is non-abelian, and isomorphic to a semidirect product of $C_p$ by $C_q$. This answers your claim 2 ( I suppose by "communicative" you mean commutative). For the proof on MSE, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700967/if-g-is-a-group-of-order-pq-where-p-and-q-are-primes-how-do-i-prove-that?noredirect=1&lq=1). The arguments there also answer the question on the subgroups.